# rx - Conditional flatMap / add condition to flowable boolean

Tags: kotlin, rxjs, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I need to show error view if status is error and `call.isEmpty()` returns `true`.

Is there a better way to achieve this result?

```
val errorVisible = states.asFlowable()
    .map { it.status == Status.ERROR }
    .flatMap { isError ->
        if (isError) call.isEmpty()
        else Flowable.just(false)
    }
```

`call.isEmpty()` returns `Flowable<Boolean>` but can return something else like `Single<Boolean>`.

**EDIT:** Another question, if `call.isEmpty()` returns `Flowable<Boolean>` how can I merge two streams (two `Flowable<Boolean>`s - `states.isError` and `call.isEmpty()`) and map it to one `Flowable<Boolean>` so it's one condition?

Comment: well, you don't need to use `map` and put both conditions into `flatMap` if this is what you're asking

Comment: @martin Yes, I can skip `map` in this case. But I was looking for a different, possibly better way of doing the same thing by changing `flatMap`. My end goal is to return `Flowable<Boolean>` when it's `isError` and `call.isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can break the condition

```
.flatMap {
  if (it.isEmpty()) {
    Observable.empty()
  } else {
    Observable.just(true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use something like this

```
val errorVisible = states.asFlowable()
        .onErrorReturn { true }
        .flatMap { Flowable.just(it.status == Status.ERROR) }
```

Comment: Where is `call.isEmpty()`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52140849/2897341

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `when` or `if` block:

```
val errorVisible = states.asFlowable()
    .flatMap {
        when(it.status) {
            Status.ERROR -> call.isEmpty()
            else -> Flowable.just(false)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was looking more of an RX way of doing this if there is any. BTW, I also added a new question.